# Divisors of an integer

Tags: nt.number-theory

Say $M$ is the number of divisors of an integer.
Is there a simple formula for the minimal integer $n$ so that
the number of divisors of $n$ is $M$?

Comment: If $M$ is ordinary - yes (ordinary in sense defined here - http://www.researchgate.net/publication/222670725_The_minimal_number_with_a_given_number_of_divisors). I guess you found that already, but that's my 2¢.

Comment: I guess the growth rate is all you could expect to say anything about.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A005179 - there are references to partial results

Comment: Given n has prime factorization with exponents a,b,c..., M is (a+1)(b+1)((c+1)..., and the exponent bases are the first however many primes.  You have an upper bound of 2^(M+1), which can be optimized quickly.  If M itself has k prime factors, you get (p_k)(kf) as a quick upper bound, where p_k is the kth smallest prime and f is the largest of the k prime factors.  However, even a greedy strategy may not yield the minimum, so you will still need to do some searching. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.09.04

Comment: Do you insist that the number of divisors is exatly $M$ or is at least $M$ what you are interested in. If you care about exact count note that this then depends quite a bit on the $M$ and not just its rough sizes (and this is what the comments refer to). To highligth something implictly in other comments. If $M$ is prime for example, it is clear that the only eligible $N$ are (M-1)th prime powers, and then clearly one needs to take a power of two. If you care just about at least $M$ this is a different question; then a keyword is "Highly composite number".  

Comment: Another sequence that you might find useful, depending on the motivation for this question, is oeis.org/A000005, the number of divisors of $n$.  The OEIS page has links to a table up to $n=100000$ and formulae for calculating the number of divisors for arbitrary $n$.  Maybe you can precompute a table of $M(n)$ in your region of interest.

Comment: @quid exactly $M$